# Distributive property of matrix multiplication?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let
$$
\mathbf{X} =
\left[\begin{array}{c}
  \mathbf{x}_1^T\\
  \mathbf{x}_2^T\\
  \vdots\\
  \mathbf{x}_n^T\\
\end{array}\right]
,\quad
\mathbf{A} =
\left[\begin{array}{cccc}
  \alpha_{1,1} & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
  0 & \alpha_{2,2} & \cdots & 0 \\
  \vdots  & \vdots  & \ddots & \vdots  \\
  0 & 0 & \cdots & \alpha_{n,n} 
\end{array}\right]
,\quad
\mathbf{t} =
\left[\begin{array}{c}
  t_1\\
  t_2\\
  \vdots\\
  t_n\\
\end{array}\right]
$$
From the distributive property of matrix multiplication, I would assume that 
$$
((\mathbf{Xw})^T - \mathbf{t}^T)\mathbf{A}^T\\
    = (\mathbf{Xw})^T\mathbf{A}^T - \mathbf{t}^T\mathbf{A}^T\\
$$
However, Maple claims that the two expressions are different - why?

Here are the maple results

[image]
with n=3

and the definitions in Maple

[image]

Comment: If that is the case, and we don't have your evidence, it's because the software is wrong.

Comment: Just updated the post :)

Comment: It's the same result, just written in a different form. Note that $(u + v - t)a = (u+v)a - ta$.

Comment: As far as I can see the two expressions given in the Maple output have the same value.  The only difference between them is that in the second output the terms $\ a_{i,i}\ $ in the products $\ \left(m_{i,1}w_{1,1}+m_{i,2} w_{2,2}-t_{i,1}\right)a_{i,i}\ $ have been distributed across two of the summands in the brackets: $\ \left(m_{i,1}w_{1,1}+m_{i,2} w_{2,2} \right)a_{i,i}-t_{i,1}a_{i,i}\ $. But these two expressions have exactly the same value.

Comment: Oh, thanks. Question answered!